# All input arrays and target arrays must have the same number of samples."- Training on single image to check if the model works in keras

Tags: machine-learning, theano, deep-learning, keras

```py
def obcandidate(inputvgg,outputmodel):

    graph = Graph()
    graph.add_input(name = 'input1', input_shape = (512, 14, 14))
    graph.add_node(Convolution2D(512, 1, 1), name = 'conv11', input = 'input1')
    graph.add_node(Convolution2D(512, 14, 14), name = 'conv112', input = 'conv11')
    graph.add_node(Flatten(), name = 'flatten11', input = 'conv112')
    graph.add_node(Dense(3136), name = 'dense1', input = 'flatten11')
    graph.add_node((Activation('relu')), name = 'relu', input = 'dense1')
    graph.add_node(Reshape((56,56)), name = 'reshape', input = 'relu')

    sgd = SGD(lr = 0.001, decay = .00005, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = True)

    graph.add_output(name = 'output1', input = 'reshape')
    graph.compile(optimizer = sgd, loss = {
    'output1': 'binary_crossentropy'})

    print 'compile success'

    history = graph.fit({'input1':inputvgg, 'output1':outputmodel}, nb_epoch=1)
    predictions = graph.predict({'input1':inputvgg})

    return graph

""

"main function"

""

if __name__ == "__main__":

    model = VGG_16('vgg16_weights.h5')
    sgdvgg = SGD(lr = 0.1, decay = 1e-6, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = True)
    model.compile(optimizer = sgdvgg, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy')
    finaloutputmodel = outputofconvlayer(model)
    finaloutputmodel.compile(optimizer = sgdvgg, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy')
    img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('000032.jpg'), (224, 224))
    mean_pixel = [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]
    img = img.astype(np.float32, copy = False)

    for c in range(3):
    img[: , : , c] = img[: , : , c] - mean_pixel[c]
    img = img.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis = 0)
    imgout = np.asarray(cv2.resize(cv2.imread('000032seg.png',0), (56, 56)))
    imgout[imgout!=0]=1
    out=imgout
    inputvgg = np.asarray(finaloutputmodel.predict(img))
    obcandidate(inputvgg,out)
```

Hi ,above is my code where i am trying to segment object candidate through graph model,

i want to check for one input if the code works or not so i am giving it one input image and the output image,

But keras gives me an error - "All input arrays and target arrays must have the same number of samples."

Can anyone tell me what do i do to see if my model runs .i am training  on one input so that i can verify that my model is correct and start training ,is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In the part where you do this - `history = graph.fit({'input1':inputvgg, 'output1':outputmodel}, nb_epoch=1)` inputvgg and outputmodel should have same number of dimensions.